# Stop Structured Streaming query gracefully

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark 2.1 and trying to stop a Streaming query gracefully.

Is `StreamingQuery.stop()` a graceful stop because I haven't seen any detailed information on this method in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingQuery.html):

> `void stop()`
>   Stops the execution of this query if it is running. 
>   This method blocks until the threads performing execution has stopped.
>   Since: 2.0.0

Whereas in the past Streaming world (DStreams) there is an [option to stop](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@stop(stopSparkContext:Boolean,stopGracefully:Boolean):Unit) the execution of the streams, with option of ensuring all received data has been processed:

> `def stop(stopSparkContext: Boolean, stopGracefully: Boolean): Unit`
>    Stop the execution of the streams, with option of ensuring all received data has been processed.
>
> `stopSparkContext`
>   if true, stops the associated SparkContext. The underlying SparkContext will be stopped regardless of whether this
>   StreamingContext has been started.
>
> `stopGracefully`
>    if true, stops gracefully by waiting for the processing of all received data to be completed

So the question is how to stop a Structured Streaming Query gracefully?

Answer (score 7):

such code can help to stop microbatch stream, if no more records are available for the consumption

```
def stopStreamQuery(query: StreamingQuery, awaitTerminationTimeMs: Long) {
   while (query.isActive) {
      val msg = query.status.message
      if (!query.status.isDataAvailable
          && !query.status.isTriggerActive
             && !msg.equals("Initializing sources")) {
      query.stop()
    }
    query.awaitTermination(awaitTerminationTimeMs)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For PySpark users, this is a Python port of @ASe answer

```
# Helper method to stop a streaming query
def stop_stream_query(query, wait_time):
    """Stop a running streaming query"""
    while query.isActive:
        msg = query.status['message']
        data_avail = query.status['isDataAvailable']
        trigger_active = query.status['isTriggerActive']
        if not data_avail and not trigger_active and msg != "Initializing sources":
            print('Stopping query...')
            query.stop()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    # Okay wait for the stop to happen
    print('Awaiting termination...')
    query.awaitTermination(wait_time)
```

Answer (score 6):

If by "gracefully" you mean that the streaming query should complete processing of data, then `void stop()` will not do that. It will just wait until the threads performing execution has stopped (as mentioned in the documentation). Which doesn't mean that it will complete the processing.

For that, we need to make the query wait till current trigger of the query is complete. Which we can check via `StreamingQueryStatus`, like this:

> while (query.status.isTriggerActive) {//do nothing}

It will wait till the query has completed the processing. And then we can call `query.stop()`.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

`StreamingQuery.stop` does not stop query gracefully, it calls `sparkContext.cancelJobGroup(all jobs generated by streaming query)`.

So to avoid it, and wait for the current batch finish, I use
https://gist.github.com/GrigorievNick/bf920e32f70cb1cf8308cd601e415d12
please note,  it works only with MicroBatchExectuion

Answer (score 1):

It depends what means "gracefully" :)

StreamingQuery stops only specific query. It waits until MicroBatch thread stops and is ready to shutdown sources. This "wait" means that the data will be processed and then thread will stop

Comment: can you please refer a source which mentions this? im confused because there is a method named processAllavaialble() which does the same thing ..but documentation says "its intended only for testing" .  https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingQuery.html#processAllAvailable()

Comment: That's not true, stop method does not wait for that batch process, it use cancel to stop all spark job scheduled by the stream.